# Get json value in VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, key

How can I get the name of a key in a json file? I have a json that I'm parsing in VB.NET and one of the 'fields' have a dynamic name (it changes). What could I do to get the key name?

For example:

...

```
"one":{  
                        "two":{  
                           "example":[  
                              {  
                                 "aaa":"test",
                                 "bbb":"test",
                                 "ccc":"test"
                              },
```

...

I'm getting correctly all the values (test, test, test...) and the keys 'one', 'two', have always the same name. But the key 'example' changes the name according the json file information. How could I identify the key text?

Comment: usually the variation will be as a result of your request, so maybe you could act based on that.  otherwise, parse it and see what is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this is solved but would like to suggest another solution for future readers.  The JavaScriptSerializer can return a nested dictionary collection (Of String, Object).  I find it easier to explore the result in debug while coding.  The code below shows an example of how to navigate the collections.

```
  Dim deserializer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer

  Dim text As String = "{""two"":{""example"":[{""aaa"":""test"",""bbb"":""test"",""ccc"":""test""}]}}"
  Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = deserializer.DeserializeObject(text)

  Dim keys As Dictionary(Of String, Object).KeyCollection
  keys = dict("two")("example")(0).Keys

  Dim aaaName As String = keys(0)
  Dim aaaValue As String = dict("two")("example")(0)(aaaName)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a piece of code that converts JSON into a XDocument here: https://github.com/dday9/.NET-JSON-Transformer

If you were to use that code, then you could get the node that represents your "two" object and then get the first child node in to. By doing this, you're essentially getting the array by an Index instead of by a name.

Here is a quick example of what I mean:

```
Dim literal As String = "{""two"":{""example"":[{""aaa"":""test"",""bbb"":""test"",""ccc"":""test""}]}}"
Dim xJSON As XDocument = JSON.Parse(literal)
Dim object_two As XElement = xJSON.Descendants("two").FirstOrDefault()
If object_two IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim first_descendent As XElement = object_two.Descendants().Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()

    If first_descendent IsNot Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine(first_descendent)
    End If
End If
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KNcsGj)

Comment: It seems very good! I'm a begginer in VB.NET. How do I call the Module Function in my main vb file? I've created an aspx file with master page (like all the other files in my project), and in the back end (.vb file) I want to use the module function (JSON.Parse(literal)...). The module is saved in a folder and my file in the same folder.

Comment: @Developer1903 - To be honest, I'm not sure. I've never developed any web applications in VB.NET, only Windows Form Applications. If it is the same as in a win form app, then all you'd need to do is: right-click the project in the solution explorer, click Add Existing Item, and then select the file.

Answer (score 1):

This piece will allow to get data from an unknown JSON structure, without having to define a class.

Sample

```
Dim serializer As System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
serializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
' {"elements":[{"handle~":{"emailAddress":"myself@example.com"},"handle":"urn:li:emailAddress:348955221"}]}
dim json as string
Dim obj As System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary(Of String, Object)
obj = serializer.Deserialize(Of System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary(Of String, Object))(json)
dim email as string=string.empty
email = If(GetJsonValue(obj, {"elements", "handle~", "emailAddress"}.ToList()), email)
```

The Function, very self descriptive:

```
''' <summary>decode json data </summary>
Public Function GetJsonValue(ByVal obj As Object,
                          ByVal key As List(Of String)) As String
   GetJsonValue = Nothing
    '   If the object is an array, assume any element can contain the key
    If obj.GetType Is GetType(Object()) Then 
        For Each newObj As Object In CType(obj, Object())
            Dim tmp As String = GetJsonValue(newObj, key)
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(tmp) Then Return tmp
        Next
    Else
        Dim objEle As System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary(Of String, Object)
        Dim keyName As String
        Dim objKey As String
        '
        keyName = key(0)
        objEle = CType(obj, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary(Of String, Object))
        objKey = objEle.Keys.ToArray()(0)

        If objEle.ContainsKey(keyName) Then
            Dim temp As Object = objEle.Item(keyName)
            If key.Count > 1 Then
                ' if the element is array, we need to get the array element and move to the next
                key.RemoveAt(0)
                Return GetJsonValue(temp, key)
            Else
                Return temp.ToString()
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

End Function